# Trying to send email via Nlog via gmail

Tags: c#, nlog, mailkit

I have an application written with c# and i'm trying to use Nlog to handle logging and email notification.  I have no problem with logging but I seem to have a big problem with email handling.

Following their recommendations in the wiki, I installed Nlog Mailkit and configured it according to directions, added targets and rules.  This is what my config file looks like now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MailKit"/>
</extensions>

  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

  <targets>
    <target 
      xsi:type="Mail" 
      name="errMail" 
      subject="test" 
      to="me@domain.com" 
      from="my_acct@gmail.com" 
      smtpUserName="my_acct@gmail.com" 
      enableSsl="true" 
      smtpPassword="pwd" 
      smtpAuthentication="Basic" 
      smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com" 
      smtpPort="587" 
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="errMail" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and as a simple test, this is my c# code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger.Error("error test");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run this, nothing seems to happen... no email, nothing.  If I swap the target with a file, I get an log file, so I know it generally works.

As another test, I dropped in some simple code to do email directly:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("my_acct@gmail.com", "From Name");
var toAddress = new MailAddress("me@domain.com", "To Name");
const string fromPassword = "pwd";
const string subject = "Subject";
const string body = "Body";

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
  Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
  Port = 587,
  EnableSsl = true,
  DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
  UseDefaultCredentials = false,
  Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};

using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
  Subject = subject,
  Body = body
})

{
  smtp.Send(message);
}
```

The smtp test works fine, so in theory there's no problem reaching gmail or sending email via gmail from my desktop.... so I can only assume there must be something I'm doing wrong either in the configuration for nlog or the call... but I can't figure out what.

I was originally trying to send via my companies smtp server but thought maybe there were some access issues preventing me from doing so so I swapped to gmail thinking it would be simpler.

I've done all the research I can and I'm pulling my hair out as to what the problem could be... HELP!!!

Comment: Please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit... so I did check and here's what the log (abbreviated) says:
```
An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS. The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:

System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```
I used the same settings in the smtp test that worked.. so i'm very confused now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/131

You can't enable ssl if using port 587 it seems like... now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the config that worked for me

1- For the from email we must enable "Allow less secure applications"
here : `https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps?pli=1&pageId=none`

2-  And the in nlog.config we include this target

```
<target xsi:type="Mail"
        name="test"
        header="Hey mouldi"
        footer="end mouldi"
        layout="${longdate}|${logger}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message} ${exception}"
        subject="Error technofix v2"
        from="...@gmail.com"
        to="...@gmail.com"
        smtpUserName="...@gmail.com"
        enableSsl="true"
        secureSocketOption="SslOnConnect"
        smtpPassword="..."
        smtpAuthentication="Basic"
        smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com"
        smtpPort="465"
/>
```